# How do I export OpenTelemetry metrics in Python aplication with OTLP?

Tags: python, prometheus, trace, metrics, open-telemetry

I am creating a prototype of application using Python with OpenTelemetry for collecting metrics, traces and for logging purposes.

Currently metrics for python in open telemetry is implemented as an experimental feature and I could not find any documentation how export metrics.

Currently I use following versions of libs

```
opentelemetry-api                      1.9.1
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-proto-grpc 1.9.1
opentelemetry-instrumentation          0.28b1
opentelemetry-instrumentation-flask    0.28b1
opentelemetry-instrumentation-logging  0.28b1
opentelemetry-instrumentation-requests 0.28b1
opentelemetry-instrumentation-wsgi     0.28b1
opentelemetry-proto                    1.9.1
opentelemetry-sdk                      1.9.1
opentelemetry-semantic-conventions     0.28b1
opentelemetry-util-http                0.28b1
```

and tried followed code

```
from opentelemetry._metrics import get_meter_provider, set_meter_provider
from opentelemetry.sdk._metrics import MeterProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk._metrics.export import PeriodicExportingMetricReader
from opentelemetry.exporter.otlp.proto.grpc._metric_exporter import (
    OTLPMetricExporter
)

TRACE_EXPORTER_ENDPOINT = os.environ.get('SERVER_TRACE_EXPORTER_ENDPOINT', 'http://localhost:4317')

#meter setup
meterExporter = OTLPMetricExporter(endpoint=TRACE_EXPORTER_ENDPOINT)
reader = PeriodicExportingMetricReader(meterExporter)
provider = MeterProvider(metric_readers=[reader])
set_meter_provider(provider)

meter = get_meter_provider().get_meter(__name__)
counter = meter.create_counter("first_counter")
counter.add(1)
```

however, the metric does not appear in local instance of Prometheus

Looking for any idea how to export metrics correctly, thank you

UPD:

added the otel-collector-config.yaml

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
exporters:
    logging:
      loglevel: debug
    jaeger:
      endpoint: jaeger:14250
      insecure: true
    prometheus:
      endpoint: "0.0.0.0:8889"
processors:
    batch:
service:
    pipelines:
        traces:
            receivers: [otlp]
            exporters: [logging, jaeger]
            processors: [batch]
        metrics:
            receivers: [otlp]
            exporters: [logging, prometheus]
```

also, tried to attach to the collector container and the only I was able to see is traces but there was no information about metrics.

Comment: Hello Maxim, could you add the configuration of your otel-collector and your prometheus? You could also try to set up the collector to export the metrics to logging, just to make sure the metrics are reaching the collector. In this example we have that config: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python/tree/a659966b950ed055f270e8700f9e39e36e5c4eda/docs/examples/metrics

Comment: Hi @JulianoCosta ,

I have updated the post and added the config you asked. Also checked the collector's log but did no see any info about metrics

Comment: Hey guys, Python SDK metrics work is still in progress and not really ready for use yet.

Comment: @dalalstreetboi3739 I guess the issue here is that there is no metric exporter interval time?

Comment: There is a default exporter interval time but the metrics sdk individual parts are not fully implemented enough to even emit basic metrics.  Please take a look at this project board for ongoing work https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python/projects/6

Comment: I believe this was an old question and this should have been resolved by now, can you please share your update here?

Comment: Looks like that was an issue of early build, It started working just after a few releases.